# Rational creation of XAML markup for readibility and sanity

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

Disclaimer: Not sure what to put in the title to make it clear as the words to be used are the ones that I don't know (yet) and am asking about. Feel free to correct.

Imagine a scenario with GUI consisting of 4x3 inputs, where every input consists of a label and a textbox. At the moment, it's done by explicitly declaring all the components and each component has the for as follows.

```
<Label x:Name="Label1"
       Content="Text1" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Margin="10,210,0,0" />
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="120"
         Height="23" Margin="10,241,0,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" />
```

Is there a recommended way to generate those from "something else", like a template or such, that's governing all the common attributes in it, eliminating the need for me to type them in over and over again (well, those were autogenerated but still...)? The alignments and sizes are tedious...

As for the margins, perhaps there's a layouting functionality? I've googled it but the hits related to XAML I've got were either suspiciously weird or relying on code behind. Is that the way to go or is it doable from XAML straight off?

Comment: I think you want to read up on styling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You're looking for an `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly configure your layout, you should use [WPF Layout Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx). In order to make the grid layout, you can use [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx), [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid(v=vs.110).aspx), etc., depending on your needs.

In order to apply several properties to the all controls inside the layout control, you can define the [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `Resources` of that control, as was mentioned already:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
            <!-- etc... -->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Row definitions here. -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Column definitions here. -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- controls ... -->

    <TextBox Text="{Binding YourProperty}"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="2"
             />

    <!-- controls ... -->

</Grid>
```

Here the style will be applied to all [TextBox's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) controls.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding (or maybe I'm asking wrong way). I'm using the *Grid* component now (that's the layout you refer to, right?) and it requires me to specify the position, which I do using margins. I'm taking about something that would set the position (and size, possibly, but that's covered with styles) of the controls I throw in there.

Comment: The Grid control has rows and columns, and you can specify the position of every control using attached properties: Grid.Row, Grid.Column, etc. You don't need to use margins to specify the position in the Grid - it is bad practice.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't ask the right question. What I meant is that if it's possible **not to** use explicit column/row assignment in the declaration of each text box. I was hoping the grid or style might be able to figure out the correct order and position based on... well... here's where I got stuck. +1 for clear code example! As for the bad practice - I had the feeling that the margins (so kindly provided and extensively applied) when pulling stuff out of the toolbox in Visual Studio were wrong way.

Comment: If it's a dynamic collection, with items being added and removed programmatically, you can use an "ItemsControl", which is able to automatically 'stack' items on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to a WPF "[Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)."  With styles, you define a set of properties that will be the same between all instances of a control which use that style.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="23" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <!-- etc... -->
</Style>

<!-- This textbox will default its property values to those defined above -->
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}" />
```

Comment: I knew there was something for that pain! How about the other part - where setter of property would be non-static? I'm guessing the style won't do. I'll need to do it in another way, right? Suggestions?

Comment: You can use data binding and triggers inside the style setters.

Comment: @stukselbax I've checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for triggers and as far I understand, it's used for events - set this or that color (or whatever other property) when this or that happens (be that click or mouse over or what not). I'd need to "trigger" upon adding a component to the frame **and** have different "style" for each (different, as to e.g. position/margin). Perhaps it's my ignorance - I just fail to see how to use triggers/binding to get there. Please explain.

Comment: Once again - you must not to use Margins to create layout - you should use the panel benefits, such as Grid.Row or Grid.Column.